# Regex to find function names, including parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to use regex to get function names, including parenthesis and parameters?

For example, given this string:

```
String s = "fun1(a1,a2) + fun2(b1,b2)";
```

it should return a string array with two elements: `"fun1(a1,a2)"` and `"fun2(b1,b2)"`

Comment: Please post your attempts so you can get a better help.

Comment: This is not really a job for regexes... Except for very simple cases (don't expect to find nested functions for instance).

Comment: I agree, I would write my own parser for this purpose, regexes is not meant to be used for such cases.

Comment: @MarounMaroun can you elaborate why regex shouldn't be used in this case? thanks

Comment: @pgschr Because it gets complicated when you have, for example, nested functions: `fun1(fun2(a2, fun3(a1,a2)))`, it's way easier to be implemented by writing a custom parser. You don't really have a "pattern" here.

Comment: but in my use case there are no nested functions, shouldn't regex be used anyways?

Comment: @pgschr regex should work check out my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
\w?\(.*?\)
```

For java:

```
\\w?\\(.*?\\)
```